# How to monitor and kill processes started as another user?

Tags: posix, sh, pid

Sometimes I'm in an environment that does not support `ps -p $PID` and I want my user to be able to find out (in a portable POSIX way) if processes I started as another user are still running and also kill them if it has been too long.

If my user ran `su anotherUser -c '/bin/sh script.sh'` and got the PID, can **my user** call `kill -0 $PID` to find out if it is still running?

Or: what is the most portable POSIX way to monitor and kill processes my user started as another user? Should I `su anotherUser -c 'kill -0 $PID'` ?

My particular use case: write a library that various kernel developers (apparently all Linux, some with BusyBox which only supports `-w` for `ps`) can include as part of their platform for a bunch of apps. Occasionally some kind of system event needs to happen (like a reboot). They've all registered arbitrary scripts that they want run whenever This happens. But the kernel side wants to ensure these all terminate in a timely fashion because This isn't supposed to take forever.

These registered scripts (and the apps) run as various users. The library runs as root (a design I inherited), but launches these scripts as the users who own them. And so the library knows the PID and only succeeds in starting a script if `su username -c 'script.sh'` works.

What do these scripts do? I don't know, but they're all written by internal friendly folks who share the same interest. It should all be benign stuff like writing text files to save app state.

(Edit: added use case, added example environment which lacks `ps -p`)

Comment: What is `script.sh ` doing? Did you write it? Can you show it?

Comment: What particular environment (not supporting `ps -p $PID`) do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general you can't, since the [`kill(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command is doing a [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) syscall (see also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)). See also POSIX [kill function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html), documented and saying

> An implementation that provides extended security controls may impose further implementation-defined restrictions on the sending of signals, including the null signal. In particular, the system may deny the existence of some or all of the processes specified by pid.

However, Linux (but not other POSIX systems) have [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

The Linux `man` page of `kill(2)` says:

> For a process to have permission to send a signal it must either be       privileged (under Linux: have the `CAP_KILL` capability), or the real
>          or effective user ID of the sending process must equal the real or
>          saved set-user-ID of the target process.  In the case of `SIGCONT` it
>          suffices when the sending and receiving processes belong to the same
>          session.  (Historically, the rules were different; see NOTES.)

However, you could use [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques to share a real or saved set-user-ID. Be careful when using these, a mistake would open a huge security hole.

Read also about [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page) (it probably would forbid what you want to do).

<sup>Your last trick `su anotherUser -c 'kill -0 $PID'` would often, but not always, work. The evil is in the details (think of a `script.sh` running setuid programs, or using capabilities on Linux, or some SELinux or docker thing,..., etc), and the details are *not* standardized by POSIX.</sup>

Perhaps setting some explicit [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) communications with your particular conventions (for the purpose of querying or killing the process, with a helper "server" or "monitoring" process), e.g. using [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets or [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s or [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s, could be wiser.

Maybe you want some [batch processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) monitor or [job scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler), e.g. [GNQS](http://gnqs.sourceforge.net/). See also [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Comment: Could I `su anotherUser -c 'kill -0 $PID'` ?

Comment: Not in a portable POSIX way, but some (and perhaps most) systems might enable that.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I suppose I'm only monitoring processes on environments where I was able to `su anotherUser -c '/bin/sh script.sh'` in the first place. Does that mean I can use the same approach to run  `kill -0` as that user?

Comment: Probably yes. But you might have strange exceptions if your `script.sh` is running setuid programs or programs using capabilities. The evil is in the details and the details are not standarized by POSIX.